# How to get multiple values from one input field in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to enter 3 data separated by a space in one input.

I want to store these 3 data in 3 different variable.

Then I want to use these variables. I'm not understanding how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean as 1 input for 3 data ? You should use 1 input per data.

Comment: If you want to get from one name, I suggest you to use three input. just use **name="yourfield[]"** in your input.

Comment: I want to enter 3 data separated by a space in one input. I want to store these 3 data in 3 different variables. I want to use these variables.@robinvrd

Comment: In PHP when you retrieve data from your form in $_POST or $_GET array, you can use the function PHP `split()` to separate values by spaces. But you could also use 3 inputs and stylize them to remove borders and make it looks like one.

Comment: To do this, you have to remember that PHP runs on the server and has finished working when the page is served, and that your inputs are on the client-side (with JS). You should precise if you want to use these values client-side or server-side, if the latter, you have to make a request such as an Ajax request to the server, or submit the form

Comment: explode() is the function you are looking for, $delimiter is ' ' (space) in your case: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```php
<input type="text" name="inputbox">

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['inputbox'])){
    foreach (explode(' ', $_POST['inputbox']) as $key => $value){
        ${'var'.$key} = $value
    }
}
```

now you can use `$var0`, `$var1` and `$var2`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given above, you can also use the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$input  = $_POST['YourFieldName'];
$input_arr = explode(" ", $input);
echo $input_arr[0]; // input 1
echo $input_arr[1]; // input 2 etc...
```

Comment: Its indeed another method a bit different fromabove